# sendgrid webhook open event is giving wrong ip address and user agent

Tags: sendgrid

SendGrid webhook open event is giving wrong ip address and user agent if an email is opened by Gmail web client.
It returns some gmail IP and fake user-agent instead of client's IP and user-agent.
Do you know how can I get client's actual IP and user-agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

If Gmail is intercepting the open tracking and proxying it through their own server, then there is little SendGrid can do about that. SendGrid will send the IP address and user-agent that the open tracking pixel receives.

Comment: Understood, thanks for your answer!

Comment: You're welcome! If this did help, would you mind marking it as correct so that others can see that it helped too? Thanks!